# MYSQL ERRORNO 150 (TinyINT Not null)

Tags: mysql, ddl

> [Err] 1005 - Can't create table 'pokebob.pn_pokedex' (errno: 150)

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pn_pokedex` (
      `pokedexId` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `memberId` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `1` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `2` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `3` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `4` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `5` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `6` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `7` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `8` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `9` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `10` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `11` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `12` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `13` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `14` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `15` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `16` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `17` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `18` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `19` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `20` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `21` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `22` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `23` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `24` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `25` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `26` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `27` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `28` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `29` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `30` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `31` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `32` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `33` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `34` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `35` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `36` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `37` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `38` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `39` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `40` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `41` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `42` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `43` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `44` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `45` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `46` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `47` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `48` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `49` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `50` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `51` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `52` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `53` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `54` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `55` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `56` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `57` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `58` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `59` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `60` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `61` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `62` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `63` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `64` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `65` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `66` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `67` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `68` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `69` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `70` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `71` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `72` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `73` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `74` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `75` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `76` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `77` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `78` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `79` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `80` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `81` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `82` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `83` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `84` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `85` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `86` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `87` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `88` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `89` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `90` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `91` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `92` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `93` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `94` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `95` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `96` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `97` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `98` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `99` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `100` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `101` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `102` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `103` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `104` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `105` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `106` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `107` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `108` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `109` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `110` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `111` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `112` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `113` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `114` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `115` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `116` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `117` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `118` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `119` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `120` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `121` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `122` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `123` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `124` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `125` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `126` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `127` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `128` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `129` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `130` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `131` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `132` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `133` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `134` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `135` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `136` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `137` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `138` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `139` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `140` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `141` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `142` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `143` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `144` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `145` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `146` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `147` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `148` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `149` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `150` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `151` TINYINT NOT NULL 
[Msg] Finished - Unsuccessfully
--------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Having 151 columns. Didn't you miss one :-) ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues that I see with your table creation:

1, You are not closing the table definition with the ending parenthesis `)` (error #1064)

```
...
`151` TINYINT NOT NULL 
);
```

2, You are required to define a `PRIMARY KEY` when using an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column (error #1075).

You can quickly achieve this by extending your AUTO_INCREMENT column definition:

```
`pokedexId` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
...
```

---

**Error #1005:**

> Cannot create table. If the error message refers to error 150, table creation failed because a foreign key constraint was not correctly formed. If the error message refers to error –1, table creation probably failed because the table includes a column name that matched the name of an internal InnoDB table.
>
> Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-error-codes.html

Answer (score 0):

From the [MySQL - FOREIGN KEY Constraints Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

> If you re-create a table that was dropped, it must have a definition that conforms to the foreign key constraints referencing it. It must have the right column names and types, and it must have indexes on the referenced keys. ***If these are not satisfied, MySQL returns error number 1005 and refers to error 150 in the error message.***